# I am getting a syntax error for my VB.net Whats wrong?

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Form1.stockCommand.Connection = requestConnection
    Form1.stockCommand.CommandText = "Insert into UserOrders(TickerSymbol,DateTime,OrderType,StockQuantity,OrderStatus) Values('" &
        Form1.StockComboBox.Text & "','" & Date.Today & "','" & Form1.TradeTypeComboBox.Text & "','" & Form1.QuantityTextBox.Text & "','PENDING')"

    Dim numOfRecords As Integer = Form1.stockCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If numOfRecords = 1 Then
        MsgBox("A new order has been added successfully")
    Else
        MsgBox("Failed to add a new order")
    End If
```

More specifically VB.NET is saying "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

All my access names correspond to the names in the code.

Thanks!

Comment: 1.  Learn about SQL Injection and how to avoid it.  2.  Step through the code in the debugger, take a look at what `CommandText` is and then copy and paste it into SQL Server Management Studio and see if it runs.

Comment: `DateTime` is a reserved word in SQL and a Type in NET.  escape it with brackets (or change the name).  SQL Parameters would make it easier to manage the SQL vs gluing bits together as well as avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Make sure your connection is open

Comment: You can debug and view the command text.  Then run that direct and see what error you get.  or it might be clear when you look at the text.

Comment: also your strings can't have any `'` in them.

Comment: It was because I was using a reserved word. Thank you guys!